# Images overlap when I use bootstrap which I don't want

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code is a part of the website which i am making and this section keeps overlapping images. How do I correct this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:white; height:700px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="images/team/app2.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="images/team/website.png" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/team/designer1.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img  src="images/team/content.png" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/team/marketing2.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of the same:

[image]

Comment: it's better if you create jsfiddle for the question

Comment: Your code works great in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes. Overriden values. Just noticed. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have all those columns in one row, they don't fit...

Answer (score 0):

Because you set image to be always 180x180 if the width will be lower than 540 (+some margins) they will overlap. You can disable it by setting `overflow: hidden;` on each column. But in your case this should not appear as you are using md columns.

So I think your problem is that you have too much columns. There should be next row each time you exceed row column limit in bootstrap default is 12.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:white; height:700px;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="images/team/app2.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="images/team/website.png" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="images/team/designer1.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <img  src="images/team/content.png" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/team/marketing2.jpg" style="height:180px;width:180px;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I used the code, all the images are in one row with the overlapping. When i used overfow:hidden, only half image is shown along with the overlapping. Should I change the size? increase it or decrease it?

Comment: even when I increase the size to 600x600 it is still overlapping

Comment: The problem is in your CSS or something else. Check if you are overriding some values bootstrap values. This code with only bootstrap works absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. Just noticed, overriden values. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your css of the images is `position: static;`

If you want them in-line with one and other, add: `display: inline-block;` or if you want it just downwards: `display: block;`

Refer to positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position